# Spring Boot property from application.properties not loaded in @Value in @Configuration class

Tags: spring-boot, properties-file

In a Spring-Boot 2.2.0 and Java8 project.

I have some properties in my application-(profileActive).properties (so, in the war) I want to externalize to a plain config file (outside the war). This is because these properties change half-yearly and it is more handy to have them in plain text files (I can use sed command, etc).

The location of the mutable properties files should be specified in the application-(profileActive).properties (it changes, upon environments) in the property *mutableproperties.project.root*

I am looking for a solution with which across the project all the @Value keep working as if nothing happened (after restart).

I'm trying to load these properties for one file using the class below:

```
@Configuration
public class MutableProperties {

    @Value("${mutableproperties.project.root}")
    private String mutablePropertiesRoot;

    private String configFile(String type) {
        StringBuffer file = new StringBuffer(mutablePropertiesRoot).append(File.pathSeparatorChar);
        file.append(type).append(".properties");
        return file.toString();
    }

    @Bean
    public PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurerDb() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource(configFile("db")));
        properties.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(false);
        return properties;
    }

}
```

The problem is mutableRoot is **null** (and it is in all the application-(profileActive).properties) as:

```
mutableproperties.project.root=/etc/properties/boot/myproject
```

I have tried with static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer but it is not suitable as the name of the file is actually the dynamic thing.

I am open to other solutions to solve the problem, but changes on JVM or actions across many classes are not suitable. This must be a surgery change that will work on an already in-production environment

Comment: Is the file you are referring to, available on the classpath?

Comment: The application-(activeProfile).properties, yes. 
The mutable-properties file is not. 
But the problem is I cannot even read the location

Comment: so you want to load all files under /etc/properties/boot/myproject and that should be part of application context ? is it so ?

Comment: Yes. This is why I am using a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer. And the location of the files you are referring to, is loaded in runtime

Comment: -Dspring.config.location can be used

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config

Comment: In my organization this is not a suitable approach. Cannot mess with JVM. Adding it in the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally abandoned the @Value within Configuration.

The solution has been having the property in a maven profile (so, the property is not hard-coded, it is in the pom), let maven create a properties file in the path set on this property, using org.codehaus.mojo.properties-maven-plugin.

With this:

1. I'm generating a dynamic properties file (not findable in eclipse, only in the war), included by maven in the war
2. In it there is a property, the path where the editable properties file lay
3. From PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer I can now load all the properties
   And yes, the name of the properties files are hard-coded, as application.properties is, not a problem

private static final String FROMPOM_PROPERTIES_LOCATION = "/frompom.properties";

private static final String MUTABLES_ROOT_PROPERTY      = "mutable.root";

```
private String mutablesLocation() throws ...{
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/frompom.properties");
    return PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource).getProperty("mutable.root");
}

private PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer(String type) {
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer properties = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    File file = new File("/" + mutablesLocation() + "mutable.properties");
    properties.setLocation(new FileSystemResource(file));
    return properties;
}

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>write-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}\frompom.properties</outputFile>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```